# iOS. Add to Passbook with Alert Dialog

Tags: ios, alert, passbook

Please, advise how I can create alert dialog, similar to Starbucks, shown in the image, when add to Apple Passbook.

[image: Starbucks alert dialog]

I've tried to use `PKAddPassesViewController`, but failed, as it wasn't clear how to get alert dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like they are presenting a standard `UIAlert` *before* presenting the user with a `PKAddPassesViewController`.

It is not possible to directly replace the Add/Cancel buttons of the `PKAddPassesViewController` with an alert.

Comment: @Entropius I would recommend is that you file an Enhancement request at http://bugreport.apple.com because the current App control in the top right of the pass is too subtle and is often missed by users.  We did discuss this with Apple at WWDC, but the more people requesting this feature, the more likely it is to happen in iOS7.